# Prove that the intersection between a quadric and a plane is always a second-order curve

Tags: analytic-geometry, quadratics, conic-sections, surfaces

My problem is simply: If you have a general quadratic surface
$$ Q: ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2fyz+2gzx+2hxy+2px+2qy+2rz+d=0.$$
prove that the intersection curve between this suface and a plane
$$ P: a_1 x + a_2 y + a_3 z + a_4 = 0.$$
is always a second-order curve (a conic section or two parallel lines).

Comment: At least one of $a_1,a_2,a_3$ is not zero. WLOG, $a_3\neq 0$. Let express $z$ from $P$ and put it into $Q$. Then we can get equation of intersection in terms of $x$ and $y$ and this equation will be equation of second-order curve, because $z$ from $P$ will be linear combination of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Perform a rotation carrying plane $P$ to plane $z=0$. The proof is then obvious.